# ¿Cómo verificar si el dato ingresado en un JOptionPane es una letra?

Tags: java, java-swing, java-8

> Buenos días, tardes o noches, quiero intentar verificar que lo ingresado en el JOptionPane sea letra, si en caso no sea así (número y caracter), quiero me arroje un error después de verificar.

> En este caso es que si se desea, registrar personal o ver personales registrados.

```
    public class Proyecto {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String decision = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("    -----Bienvenido al sistema de registro de personal-----"
                                 + "\nDesea registrar personal o ver los personales registrados: ");
    
    
        }


    }
```

Comment: Buen día. Se entiende lo que buscas, pero deberías ser más específico.Además, ¿qué has buscado o qué has hecho para resolver el problema? Existe mucha documentación que podrías consultar antes de formular una pregunta https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/

Comment: Quería saber en caso de que ingrese un número (1,5,6, etc) o caracter(´{}´}.,-) en vez de (registrar personal o ver los personales registrados), verificarlo para que me de un error en caso de que ingrese un caracter o un número, estoy haciendo un pequeño proyecto, ya que recién estoy iniciando en la programación y tengo lo más básico por no decir poco, disculpa de antemano por no ser lo más específico posible, pero lo lograré con el tiempo :D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existe la clase stringUtils, tiene varias funciones para validar cadenas y determinar si es numerico.
http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#isNumericSpace-java.lang.CharSequence-

Para arrojar el error puede ser con un if en caso de que devuelva que es un numero
Si es true significa que si es numérico

```
if(StringUtils.isNumeric(yourvar)) {
 //Lanzar mensaje de error
}
```

Comment: Ohh! mucha gracias, estaré leyendo la documentación, gracias por la ayuda hermano ♥